# Laravel relationships: hasManyThrough a model with on an pivot table

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have 3 models in Laravel:

`Item`
`ModifierGroup`
`Modifier`

An `Item` can have many `ModifierGroups` via an intermediate table:

```
public function modifierGroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\ModifierGroup', 
            'menu_item_modifiers', 
            'item_id', 
            'group_id'
        )->using('App\MenuItemModifier')
         ->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
         ->withPivot('position');
    }
```

A `ModifierGroup` has many `Modifiers`:

```
public function modifiers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\Modifier', 
            'group_id', 
            'id'
        )->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
    }
```

My question is whether it's possible to have a function on the `Item` that gets to the `Modifiers`, going through the `ModifierGroup` (and its pivot)? `HasManyThrough` doesn't seem to fit with an pivot table involved or does it?

Comment: Why is it that you would want to go through the ModifierGroup table exactly?  Is there a reason you aren't just defining a modifiers() method on the Item class?  This isn't exactly how you would use a pivot table either.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a `BelongsToMany` relationship by "skipping" the `ModifierGroup` table:

```php
public function modifiers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Modifier',
        'menu_item_modifiers',
        'item_id',
        'group_id',
        null,
        'group_id'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using pivot tables, but not in the way that you are using them.  As I assume you have three tables - each associated with your models (`Item`, `ModifierGroup`, `Modifier`), you haven't set up pivot functionality as you don't actually have pivot tables.  To do this you would require one table to link `Item` to `ModifierGroups` and another to link `ModifierGroups` to `Modifier`.

**To start, lets create the tables using Artisan:**

```
php artisan generate:pivot Item ModifierGroup
```

now, we have a table called item_modifier_group (I believe?).  This table should have two columns, item_id and modifier_group_id.  These are the keys Eloquent will use to connect to the items and modifier_groups tables.  Now, in our query we can access and item's modifier groups by using the following query:

```
public function modifierGroups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ModifierGroup');
}
```

This means that when you call `$item->modifierGroups()` you will get a collection of all modifier groups having an id of `$item->id`.

This process can then be repeated for the `ModifierGroups` to `Modifiers` relationship:

```
php artisan generate:pivot ModifierGroup Modifiers
```

Now define the modifiers method in the `ModifierGroup` model:

```
public function modifiers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modifier');
}
```

Now we have our pivot tables set up, and our relationships defined in one direction (just add similar methods to models to get Items via Modifiers)

The final piece of the pie is Eager Loading (it's amazing).  **Get item, with modifiers through the appropriate groups** like so:

```
Item::with('modifierGroups.modifiers')->findOrFail('id');
```

Now there are other ways you could have gone about this problem, and some may even be more valid, however the huge benefit to doing it this way is the flexibility.  You now have a way to connect Items, ModifierGroup and Modifiers with pivot tables and with a simple eager loaded query, can get any collection combination you deem necessary.  Hope this helped!  This is definitely the longest solution I've ever written on here...

**For future reading I recommend:**

[Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) - Nested Eager Loading

[Defining Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) - Many-to-Many

Comment: Thanks for the long solution! I do have a pivot table of menu_item_modifiers with item_id, group_id and position.

Comment: If this is the case then you should modify the belongsToMany() method to have the table name and both keys.  The Many-to-Many docs outline this well.  Cheers.